# How can i adjust height and width a layer on div

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can i adjust height and width of the layer on the card and one thing i want only the close button should work and everything will be unclickable. please can any one help me to find the solution...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="">

    <div class="modal-content" >
      <div class="" style="padding: 44% 50%;opacity: 60%;position: absolute;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);align-items: center;z-index: 1;">
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-wrap" style="width: 6rem;">
      <p class="text-break">sdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsd</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted ? The modal only `closes` if you click on `X` at the top.

To disable modal via keyboard `esc` or clicking outside the modal we need to add this to our modal `div`

```
data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"
```

**Using overlay**

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="">

    <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="" style="height: calc(100% - 70px);width:100%;opacity: 60%;position: absolute;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);align-items: center;z-index: 1;">


      </div>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="z-index: 1;">
      <span aria-hidden="true" >&times;</span>
    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-wrap" style="width: 6rem;">
        <p class="text-break">sdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsd</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**No Overlay**

If you do not want any overlay then you can use this code.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="">

    <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="" style="width:100%;opacity: 60%;position: absolute;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);align-items: center;z-index: 1;">


      </div>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="z-index: 1;">
      <span aria-hidden="true" >&times;</span>
    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-wrap" style="width: 6rem;">
        <p class="text-break">sdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsd</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give me that code that you have recently posted.....I have got some idea.......please

Answer (score 1):

The close button **'x'** dont work? why?

Change z-index of `modal-content` child div to **0** and add some **height and width** to it

```
 <div class="" style="padding: 44% 50%;opacity: 60%;position: absolute;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);align-items: center;z-index: 0;width:100%;height:100%;">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="">

    <div class="modal-content" >
      <div class="" style="padding: 44% 50%;opacity: 60%;position: absolute;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);align-items: center;z-index: 0;width:100%;height:100%;">
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-wrap" style="width: 6rem;">
      <p class="text-break">sdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsd</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="z-index:1;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want the overlay in **modal background** remove `opacity and padding`

```
 <div class="" style="position: absolute;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);align-items: center;z-index: 0;">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="">

    <div class="modal-content" >
      <div class="" style="position: absolute;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);align-items: center;z-index: 0;">
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-wrap" style="width: 6rem;">
      <p class="text-break">sdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsd</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```